# C# EF Calculated Property does NOT compute when record is not yet saved to the Database

Tags: c#, blazor, webapi, ef-core-3.1, computed-properties

I am relatively new to C#, EF, and Code First...and I'd like to ask for help to teach me what I am doing wrong or how to make this work?

I have a simple class coded like this:

```
public class RaceEvent
{
    public RaceEvent()
    {
        EventName = "";
        TimeStarted = null;
        TimeEnded = null;
    }

    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? TimeStarted { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? TimeEnded { get; set; }

    /* This is my Computed Property */
    public double EventDuration
    {
        get
        {
            if (TimeStarted != null && TimeEnded != null)
            {
                var result = TimeEnded.Value.Subtract(TimeStarted.Value); 
                return result.TotalMinutes <= 0 ? 0 : result.TotalMinutes; 
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

A few more details:

1. Client-side is a Blazor WebAssembly project
2. Server-side (Web Api) is an ASP.NET Core Web Application project

My Problem is: The `EventDuration` computed property **computes and updates the values perfectly when I am editing a record** (*the object is a record retrieved from the database thru the webapi server*)..but the computed property **IS NOT COMPUTING** (*or does nothing*) **when I am in create new record** (*the object has only been instantiated with a* `new RaceEvent()` *in client-side, and has not yet been posted to the server-side*)

Comment: What do you mean with: "IS NOT COMPUTING". What is the value of EventDuration, after creating with "new RaceEvent()". It should be 0 right?

Comment: Thank you for the response @TheTanic...if I just newly create the RaceEvent object, changing values of either TimeStart or TimeEnded will result to 0 Event Duration, even if I put values like 6:00AM (TimeStart) and 8:00AM (TimeEnded), EventDuration will always be 0...but if I save the RaceEvent object to the database, then edit the RaceEvent, the EventDuration will now be computing as I change the values real-time... :(

Comment: @TheTanic...I finally found the problem, it is because I'm an IDIOT! I messed up my create.razor page! hahaha thanks again!!